# Order of Execution of @BeforeTest method in testNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to execute testcases using testng.xml. I have placed all the test running classes inside one test. While executing i am noticing that the @BeforeTest method of 2nd class (dashboard class) is executing first. I want to execute the @BeforeTest methods of all classes to execute in same executing order as classes in testng.xml file. Please find below image.

[image]
As per image, i want to execute @BeforeTest methods of LoginPage class, then DashboardPage class and so on..

I have used alwaysRun=True for all @BeforeTest and @BeforeClass i have used for mentioned classes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute `dependOnMethods` form the annotation.

This little test:

```
public class StackOFTest {

    @BeforeTest
    public void first() {
        System.out.println("First");
    }

    @BeforeTest(dependsOnMethods = {"first"})
    public void second() {
        System.out.println("Second");
    }

    public static class SubTest extends StackOFTest {

        @BeforeTest(dependsOnMethods = "second")
        public void subFirst() {
            System.out.println("- First");
        }

        @Test
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
First
Second
- First
Test
```

Comment: Do i have to extend the class in order to use dependsOnMethods in @beforetest in different class